# OnSubmit not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, onsubmit

I need some help, when i use `onSubmit="return false"` it stops the submit like it should.

However i need to do a check first and return the result with a function.

```
echo form_open('Gebruiker/updateProfiel', array('onSubmit' => 'return validate()'), $hidden);

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(){
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Yes i'm using CodeIgniter (need to use it for school). Any help please? Using the function it just won't stop the submit.

Comment: solved it sorry guys